SwipeItem Command Binding Misbehavior
I had view model expose two RelayCommand:
 [ObservableProperty]
 private ObservableCollection<MyModel> data;
 [RelayCommand]
 private async Task Edit(MyModel m) {}
 [RelayCommand]
 private async Task Delete(MyModel m) {}

in the view
<CollectionView ItemsSource="Data">
 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:MyModel">
        <SwipeView>
          <SwipeView.RightItems>
               <SwipeItems>
                  <SwipeItem Text="Edit" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MyViewModel}}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                  <SwipeItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MyViewModel}}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
               </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView>
        <!-- render MyModel -->
    </DataTemplate>
 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

Somehow, the edit button doesn't work; and delete button triggers "Edit", what could be wrong?
I would like to see two swipitems are handled by their own commands.

You can click the button if use the SwipView.LeftItems?

Same deal.  Modified the xaml to add buttons in "render MyModel" section with exact same command binding, which work as expected;   If I swap the two SwipeItems, still only one command works and it's for another swipeitem.   I'm using .Net 8.0.70 runtime.

Debugger shows an error, I have no idea where it came from: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Microsoft.UI.Xaml.GridLength>' to type 'Double'; BindingExpression: Path='TemplateSettings.CompactPaneGridLength' DataItem='Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SplitView'; target element is 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SplineDoubleKeyFrame' (Name='null'); target property is 'Value' (type 'Double').

Did you set the width for the elements in the SwipeView? I tested the code you provide, and it worked well.

If you set the Binding Source as MyViewModel, then the Path should be Path=EditCommand instead of  Path=BindingContext.EditCommand
